# Install project from github

Tags: github, reactjs, installation

I need to install this [project/code](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal) as its required for a project I am working on.

Is the easiest way to just grab whats in the Dist folder and copy it into the project?

Do all projects have npm install commands? in the documentation this one doesn't appear to have any explanation for installing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer and have been installing npm packages for fun every since ;) I followed this tutorial [Node.js and npm into for VS2015](https://medium.com/@frankchen2016/node-js-and-npm-introduction-for-visual-studio-2015-50ed9db8da22)

I found editing the packages.json file first fixed it for me. Cause after doing so then running the commands it installed perfectly fine. Thanks for the answers guys, did help me find the issue and the eventual solution.

Answer (score 2):

See this page for npm:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/package-management.html

I guess only if a project is shared on npm, you can use npm commands.

Answer (score 2):

For this particular project, you *can* use `npm`, as you can see by searching for the project on [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal).

`npm install --save react-modal` will install the package in your project.

In general, however, yes, if a project doesn't have installation instructions and it isn't on `npm`, then you will have to download the code from github.